# Pinnacle Studio 23 - 'JPG Noise'/White border added to .png images

Tags: pinnacle

Every .png image I import ends up with a slight white border. Mostly it's not that noticable, but other times it is extremely noticable.

[image: Example of white border]

The video is set to Widescreen (16:9) and size HD 1920x1080, every single .png file is 1920x1080px big.

I've double checked to make sure that the white border is NOT on the original .png file and only appears once imported into Pinnacle Studio.

It seems like some kind of resizing issue, however there should be no resizing happening.

I feel like there must be some general project-wide setting to fix this, but after long research, I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem only existed within the editor and when exported as HD 720p video. Exporting it as HD 1080p fixed the issue in the exported video.